# UIButton with resizable Image

Tags: ios, uiimage

Ok guys,

i know i am doing something wrong, but i cannot figure that out. here is the code that will 
put the resizable image for the normal button state.

```
self.loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 314, 44);
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginbutton_image"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,10.0,0.0,10.0)];
    [self.loginButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:self.loginButton];
```

Here is the image

[image]

either the image asset is wrong or the code.

the image is of 21 px width.
the cap inset of 10 & 10 on left right leaves 1Px to resize.

does any one spot what i am doing wrong.

thanks all for stopping by
Arun

Comment: are you sure `image` is not `nil`?

Comment: yep i check it. its all good.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jpj1l.png this is how it looks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should do it this way:

```
self.loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 314, 44);
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginbutton_image"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,10.0,0.0,10.0)];
[self.loginButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:self.loginButton];
```

This way you are setting the background image property of the button. The background image is already attached to the button view, so no need to addSubview.

Comment: i am really sorry. I am actually setting the image for the button state.

Comment: no problem, but the image you posted seems an image for a background. If you make an UIButtonTypeCustom, the button wont have a background. If you want to make a styled button, with that image as a background, you should use the code I posted.

Comment: i've changed the setImage:image for setBackgroundImage:image

Answer (score 0):

try

```
self.loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 314, 44);
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginbutton_image"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10]; //assuming the height is 44
    [self.loginButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:self.loginButton];
```

Comment: same result. But stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth method is deprecated in iOS 5.0. so its not a good idea.